# Issue with UV mapping and Texture paint tools

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting

I'm very new to Blender so sorry if this is quite obvious. I've been using Darrin Lile's character modelling tutorials on YouTube. It was all fine up until texturing. To briefly explain what the issue is, when using the 'Texture Paint' mode in Blender (the one that allows you to paint directly onto the object), the paint is appearing on the opposite side of some parts. For example, if I add paint onto the stomach, it will appear on the character's back.

I'm hoping the solution is something very simple but it's possible I've messed something up with the UV maps. However, my UV map seemed fine.

If anyone could help with this that would be great. Thanks for reading!

Here's the download link to my model: [image]

Comment: do you mean it also appears on another part? It would mean that some parts of your UVmap are overlapping

Comment: Can you check in edit mode that your mesh face normals are all pointed outward? This is a common problem where texture paint is on the 'wrong side' of the mesh at times due to the normals needing to be corrected.

Comment: Hi @moonboots, thanks for the answer. I can confirm that occasionally the paint appears on multiple parts. I think I can recall the tutorial I was using suggesting a way to move the UV islands around so I'll see what I can do and get back to you on that.

Comment: for a direct painting on texture, when you unwrap, use the Smart UV Project option, it will create islands that won't overlap by default, then paint on the 3D view (or UV/Image Editor)

Comment: Hi @CraigDJones, thanks for the answer. Sorry, I'm not really too sure what you mean exactly by that. If you mean, is the paint appearing on the inside of the model aswell, then yes it is.

Comment: Hi again @moonboots. Sadly that hasn't quite worked. I've tried using the smart uv project option as well as the average island scale and pack islands options. I can also confirm there are no overlaps. Still when i paint on one side of the model it appears on the other side. Also for some reason, the paint ends up on some other objects that have a different uv map and are not selected. If it helps I'm also using the mirror modifier, but don't think that would be the problem. Thanks again for responding.

Comment: oh ok so apply the Mirror modifier and see if it works   ;)

Comment: @moonboots Sadly still no positive results :(

Comment: have you unwrapped again after applying the mirror? maybe share your file...

Comment: @moonboots Just applied the mirror and then unwrapped it again but still same result. I'd gladly share the file but... having a few technical difficulties with the internet on my PC currently. When the internet finally comes back up where should I send you the file? Assuming that I can't send it on this discussion page. Thanks!

Comment: put here on this page: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/   enter the URL of this page and then upload

Comment: @moonboots Think that should be it uploaded and here's the link [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6209" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6209/) I'll put that in the question description as well. Thanks very much for taking your time to look into this, and there's no need to rush at all!

Comment: oh ok you need to recalculate your normals: in Edit mode select all and ctrl N. By the way you have a lot of faces, you should simplify a bit  ;)

Comment: @moonboots Ah yeah that did it. Knew it would be something so simple, thanks so much! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a Normal issue: Go in *Edit* mode, select all, and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> to recalculate the normals (<kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> in 2.8).

Comment: ok I correct my answer